# How to configure AWS CLI for an account for multiple regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am using AWS CLI to setup ECS clusters in different regions,so how can i configure AWS CLI on an instance for two different regions.

Answer (score 8):

You can simply specify the region the AWS CLI should operate on. Either use the [command line parameter `--region`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-command-line.html), like:

```
aws --region us-east-1 ecs ...
```

And alternative is to use the [environment variable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-environment.html) `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`, like:

```
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1 aws ecs ...
```

A third option would be to configure [multiple profiles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-multiple-profiles.html) for the AWS CLI in `~/.aws/config` and set a different region for each profile.

Comment: after setting none for region in aws configure. and passing --region parameter in CLI. It worked. Thanks

Comment: @namanparihar Your comment is actually the right answer to the question